# "ValueError: 'url(#color-1)' is not a recognized color." SVG in manimce

Tags: python, manim

I am trying to display an SVG in my scene. when running, I encounter this error `ValueError: 'url(#color-1)' is not a recognized color.` does anyone know what I could do to fix this?
this is my code:

```py
from manim import *

class myScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        self.play(FadeIn(SVGMobject("silver.svg")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This just means the SVG has a gradient. Gradients don't work with animations like `FadeIn()` or `DrawBorderThenFill()`.

To fix this:

1. Open the SVG file in Adobe Illustrator or such
2. Get the start hex and end hex of the gradient with the angle
3. Give static colors to all gradients
4. Replicate that in Manim using `color_gradient()`

I hope this helps (even though it's a bit too late)